# How to read custom section data in web.config with minimum code

Tags: c#, web-config

here is my custom section in web.config. now i want read data by c#

```
<configuration>
  <MailList>
    <MailID id="test-uk@mysite.com" Value="UK" />
    <MailID id="test-us@mysite.com" Value="US" />
    <MailID id="test-ca@mysite.com" Value="CA" />
  </databases>
</configuration>
```

suppose i want technique by which i can only read data based on value. if i supply UK as value then function will return uk mail id `test-uk@mysite.com`.

guide me how easily i can do this writing very minimum code. thanks

Comment: use the <appSettings> tag and add the elements with key=" " value=" "

Comment: similar example http://forums.asp.net/t/2022955.aspx?How+to+traverse+in+location+section+in+web+config+asp+net+webform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your XML seems to be broken:

It must be something like that:

```
<configuration>
  <MailList>
    <MailID id="test-uk@mysite.com" Value="UK" />
    <MailID id="test-us@mysite.com" Value="US" />
    <MailID id="test-ca@mysite.com" Value="CA" />
  </MailList>
</configuration>
```

This code should do what you want:

```
        string country = "UK";
        var result =
            XDocument.Load("~/web.config")
                .Element("configuration")
                .Element("MailList")
                .Elements("MailID")
                .First(el => el.Attribute("Value").Value.Equals(country))
                .Attribute("id")
                .Value;

        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the appsettings tag in your webconfig like:

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="test-uk@mysite.com" value="UK" />
<add key="test-us@mysite.com" value="US" />
<add key="test-ca@mysite.com" value="CA" />
```

And after that you have your class:

```
public class WebConfigreader
{
    public static string AppSettingsKey(string key)
    {
        if (WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings != null)
        {
            object xSetting = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
            if (xSetting != null)
            {
                return (string)xSetting;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

And in your logic you are calling just:

```
String strUk = WebConfigreader.AppSettingsKey("test-uk@mysite.com");
```